# Recursion over one value, but storing lists along the way

Tags: python, list, recursion

My question is i have a function as follows:

```
def myfunc(a):
    b=[]
    b.append(a)
    return myfunc(a-1), b*
```

*= I am aware this will break my function
is there any possible way to allow `b` to update with my used `a` values while having my function continue running? The code to which the question pertains is a max val. proble. So i have a list of weights and values, and a max. allowable weight. My function finds the max no problem, but I'd like to see what values i'm using to get there. i.e. w=[1,2,3] v=[4,7,2]
max weight= 3, max val is = 11. What I'd like my function to display in edition are list such as weights used=[1,2] and values used=[4,7]. Sorry for the lack of actual code posted, the site is not allowing it.

Comment: If you'd like to learn how to format your posts nicely, check out the [format guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, if you have code you'd like to show, edit your question again and add it, we can format it correctly if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a default argument.

```
def myfunc(a, lst=None):
    if lst is None:
        lst = []
    lst.append(a)
    if a > 0:
        myfunc(a-1, lst)
    return lst

print(myfunc(5))  # prints: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: This was actually very helpful, I cannot believe I missed this option the first few times around

Answer (score 1):

You mean, something like this?

```
def myfunc(a):
    if a == 0:
        return [a]
    return myfunc(a-1) + [a]

myfunc(5)

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Kind of. Is there anyway to format it to look more like what I have above. The problem I'm working on is much more complicated, and something along those line would be much more helpful. Basically the ability to return a list I exclusively use for storing, along with a value, a in this case, which I will use for recursion. If not I shall try and play around with this.

Comment: And what exactly is supposed to be returned from `myfunc()`? sure, it's a two-valued tuple where the second element is a list, but what's the first element? the recursion in the question is ill-defined, it doesn't even have a base case

Comment: My apologies, as I do not know the terminology for this that well. But   the actual code im working on, which this site will not allow my to post, is a max value problem. So i'm essentially returning a max(value 1, value 2) each time. My base cases are 2 lists, weights, and values, along with a max. weight int. I am attempting to return multiple lists of data. I.E. a current weight used list, and value attempted list, current max list ect... Sorry about the lack of clarity.

Comment: Add clarifications to the question-at-hand to the main post, rather than keeping in it the comments so everybody can more easily see what you need.